# localstorage saves an empty object

Tags: javascript

```html
<table id="products" class="table table-dark table-hover" style="text-align: center;width:45%;margin: 4px">
    <tr>
     <th>Car</th>
     <th>Model</th>
     <th>Price</th>
     <th>Basket</th>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="buyProduct(this)">
     <td>Mercedes_Benz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="buyProduct(this)">
     <td>BMW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="buyProduct(this)">
     <td>Toyota</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table id="basket" class="table table-dark table-hover" style="text-align: center;width:45%;margin: 4px"></table>
```

i have a problem with storing data to localstorage , i want to save clicked  to localstorage and onload get it but on local storage it shows empty object, this is code,, Thank you in advance

```js
var row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var prod = document.getElementById('products');
var bas = document.getElementById('basket');
var k = 0;
var arr = [];
function buyProduct(x) {
 arr[k] = x;
 localStorage.setItem("sold"+k, JSON.stringify(arr))
 
 x.remove();
 x.removeAttribute('onclick')
 bas.append(x);
 k++;
 
}
window.onload = function() {
 var stored;
 if(localStorage) {
  for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
   stored = localStorage.getItem("sold"+i);
   console.log(JSON.parse(stored))
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: so, the function `buyProduct` is where the localStorage.setItem is used ... but that function is never called ... mysetery solved

Comment: buyProduct function is used on html dom element,here is html

Comment: <tr>
     <th>Car</th>
     <th>Model</th>
     <th>Price</th>
     <th>Basket</th>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="buyProduct(this)">
     <td>Mercedes_Benz</td>
     <td>c 180</td>
     <td>4200$</td>
     <td><img src="online-store (2).png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="buyProduct(this)">
     <td>BMW</td>
     <td>745i</td>
     <td>8500$</td>
     <td><img src="online-store (2).png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="buyProduct(this)">
     <td>Toyota</td>
     <td>Corolla</td>
     <td>12000$</td>
     <td><img src="online-store (2).png"></td>
    </tr>

Comment: NB: use `arr.push( <value> )` instead of maintaining your own array-length variable.

Comment: in your function buyProduct x will be the tr element not any value, so if you use JSON.stringify it will return empty array. So, you want to have value then you have pass in your function

Comment: var arr = []; It is empty. Didn't find any arr.push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke `onclick="buyProduct(this)"` you're saving the DOM `<tr>` elements in the array, not their associated values.

The `JSON.stringify()` function finds no enumerable properties on those elements, and so saves an empty object.

If you actually want the contents of the `<td>` that's within the row you could use this:

```
arr.push(this.querySelector('td').textContent);
```

NB: note use of `push` to add to the end of the array instead of the error-prone practice of maintaining your own variable tracking the array's length.